# Classifier for matching two sets with similar ID strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have 2 sets of data that have common feature sets but different labels to their ID names.

I want to see if there's an optimal classifier that can help me choose which name matches are the best choices based off these features.

`Set 1` looks like:

```
Name         ID1           code1          move1        year
Highland     1             nc             st           2002
Highland     4             nc             st           2001
Highland     gt3           nc             st           2002
Highland     gt2           nc             st           2003
Mark         wt1           ns             st           2000
Mark         ws1           ns             st           1945
Mark         ost6          nc             ct           2002
Niko         1             ng             ct           2000
.
.
```

`Set 2` looks like:

```
Name         ID2           code2          move2        year
Highland     gt1           nc             st           2002
Highland     gt3           nc             st           
Highland     2             nc             st           2003
Highland     gt4           nc             st           2001
Mark         t1            ns             st           2000
Mark         s1            nsi            st           
Mark         ost6          nci            ct           2002
Niko         1             ngi            ct           2000
.
.
```

As you can see there are some differences in both sets but `Name` is always the same - the IDs sometimes almost match and sometimes match perfectly. Other times the `codes` or `moves` match or are close and sometimes the years are just missing in general for one set.

I've calculated `fuzzy ratios` which use `Levenshtein Distances` for these IDs but they aren't enough for me to really make a good match.

Is there a way I can better identify these IDs using something like SVM?

Comment: Are you trying to match complete row of set1 with set2?

Comment: I'm trying to match `ID1` with `ID2` using the similarities in their ID names and their feature's similarities. So I think matching the two IDs kind of indirectly matches their rows together.

Comment: I was thinking there might be a way to turn each row into a tuple and somehow turn the tuples into groupings that an SVM could run through?

Comment: what ive done in the past is assign weights to different match types.  so, name would get a very heavy weight.  then trailing digit of id1, year, etc.  highest score “wins”.  you manipulate coefficients and weights till you fit your pop1==pop2.  it’s not really easy to demonstrate, but the idea becomes clear enough when you start working with it.  The Levenstein distance, IMHO, is a bit of an expensive red herring - you need to be mire directive.

Comment: Is there a worked example I could see to better understand what you mean, @JLPeyret?

Comment: sorry.  would be really complex to put together. and this “straight” Python too, not ML.  but basically match each S1 row with its S2 Name== neighbors.  Then pick best fits.  a full match on id might be 0.5 but on year is 0.3.  a partial match on trailing id digits might be 0.4. year and id together might add up. assign and prune in order of confidence so that an S2 can only match one S1. the idea is to line up your calculation results with how you eyeball/classify them manually.

Answer (score 1):

Try `fuzz.token_set_ratio()` instead of `fuzzy.ration()`.
Using fuzz.token_set_ratio() you will get a good matching.

For more information visit the [docs](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy#token-set-ratio).